Visual Studio 2022 Refactoring Funtionalities With Git Source Control Applies Changes From Old File Versions
Using git source control on a C# solution and visual studio 2022, there seems to be problems with some visual studio refactoring functionality.

First example:
When I use the rename member functionality (ctrl-r ctrl-r by defualt) it successfully renames a member across multiple files. However, this gets picked up by source control and reverts changes that were on the branch already from a previous commit. I.e. unopened file where a simple rename operation occured will have detected changes which effectively revert the file to an earlier version before the current version that someone else pushed.
Second example:
I will often call a method which doesn't yet exist, and then right click the method -> quick actions and refactoring -> Generate method to create the method as I defined it. If this happens in another file which I don't have open, it will generate the method as expected but also add changes to the file which revert it to a previous version before the version someone else pushed.

I am making an assumption that the file is being reverted to the last time I opened it (even though my local branch has the correct version) but haven't gone through the proper troubleshooting to verify that guess. What I do know is that it is detecting changes that I did not make, and those changes amount to a revert of the file to some point in time.
Does anyone know a setting or have they experienced this? For example, a setting that forces visual studio to "open" the file or something before refactoring it? I looked in visual studio's git settings for this, but I couldn't see anything that seemed to reflect this behavior.

Update 4/11: Opening the files ahead of time seem to prevent this from happening, as suspected. When using the rename refactor, using shift-enter allows me to flick through all of the files that will be changed, which seems to be as good as opening them, but its hard to confirm either of these behaviors with my limited time.

I use refactoring in a similar way, particularly the rename member function.  I have tried to recreate these senarios and cant. I am using VS2022 17.9.6 against git version 2.43.0.windows.1
what versions are you using?  Does this happen on more than 1 installation of Visual Studio, say on another machine?

Yes, it happens for a couple team members. It's difficult to recreate because you have to have multiple people make changes in sequence, and you can't open the affected files locally first.
